# Font weights appear indistinguishable

Tags: bug, support, design

Code Review is the only website on which font weights behave weirdly - for me (using Linux Mint 18.2 and Firefox 55):

1. Some bold text:  **hello world**. 

   ... but it doesn't seem bold! It's the same weight as the rest of the text.
2. Headings:

   ## Level 1 heading `some code`

   ### Level 2 heading `some code`

   #### Level 3 heading `some code`

   the heading text has regular weight (unlike the norm on SX website), while the source code snippets in headings - is in bold.

I'm not the only one seeing this, right?

---

Screenshot of the above:

[image]

---

Comment: Make sure to check the default fonts in your browser configuration. I did have issues with italic display for the default font, might be a similar thing.